# Segmentation Fault from Scanf Int

Tags: c, scanf

I have no idea why i am getting a segmentation fault.  Every other instance of this I see online has a segmentation fault because the variable in scanf is a pointer.  Mine is not and I still get the error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
        int grade;
        struct Node *next;
};

int main()
{
        int input;
        struct Node *head, *current;
        current = head;
        printf("Enter Grades: \n");
        do
        {
            scanf("%d",&input);
            current->grade = input;
            struct Node *new_node  = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            current->next = new_node;
            current = current->next;
        }while(input != -1);
        return 0;

        current = head;
}
```

Comment: you get seg fault because you havent allocated memory for the struct before statement current->grade=input, you should allocate memory with malloc head=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

Answer (score 2):

It is this line, not scanf

```
current->grade = input;
```

As you didn't allocate memory for the head

Comment: Oh, ok. Is that done with malloc?  similar to how I created new_node?

Comment: struct Node *head =(struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

Comment: Ok thank you and I don't have to do that with current because im just setting equal to head?  Also what is the purpose of (struct Node *)?

Comment: @MikeOles you dont need explicit cast (struct Node *) in C, since malloc returns void *, its just a matter of prefrence

Comment: @Mike Oles , Simpler: `struct Node *head = malloc(sizeof *head);`